# Criando gráficos com JSON e Highcharts

Tags: html, highcharts

Estou tentando utilizar um simples exemplo fornecido pelo Highcharts para a criação de um gráfico, porém não estou obtendo sucesso.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Highcharts Example</title>

      <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

        var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
        };

        $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

data.json

```
[
[1,12],
[2,5],
[3,18],
[4,13],
[5,7],
[6,4],
[7,9],
[8,10],
[9,15],
[10,22]
]
```

Minha dúvida é: por que o gráfico não é criado? Se eu quisesse alterar o formato para `[{"a","b"}]` como eu deveria alterar a passagem dos dados para o gráfico?

Comment: O objeto `options` é bem complexo, onde está ele? senão vai dar erro na consola se tentar usar `options.series[0].data = data;`. Dê uma olhada aqui e complete a sua pergunta: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a segunda pergunta, poderia esclarecer?

Answer (score 0):

Testei o seu HTML e o que parecia ser o problema que não criava o gráfico é que a biblioteca do Highcharts parece ter uma dependência do jQuery, e o jQuery está sendo declarado só depois do Highcharts. Tente mudar para a seguinte ordem:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```